# nothing returned in iterating Python function

Tags: python

Nothing is returned when I try iterating a function in Python.
Code is like this

```
def count(num):
    if (num > 10):
        return(num)
    if(num<=10):
        new = num + 1
        count(new)     
nummer = count(8)
```

If I do count(22), it returns 22. But when I do count(8), it doesnt return anything. I would like this function to return '11' but it return nothing.
Probably something wrong in my thinking but I really can't figure it out.
I hope someone can help me.

Thx,
Peter

Comment: Where do you return if number is less than 10?

Comment: then it starts the function again. It adds +1 and then goes to the function again until it reaches 11. So, it only should return 11 or if you have entered a higher number, it should return this one.

Comment: No, it doesnt. It *calls* the function again, but the original function call still needs something to return (likewise for any subsequent function calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to include a second return, in case your number is lower or equal than 10. Besides, you could have a slightly shorter code. Calling the function is not sufficient.

You are trying to evaluated whether a number `x` is greater or lower than 10. But this number can **EITHER** be greater **OR** lower. Therefore when you put

```py
if num>10:
  pass
```

you don't need another if statement, since if `num` is not greater than 10 it is lower or equal to 10.

```py
def count(num):
    if (num > 10):
        return(num)
    else:
        new = num + 1
        return count(new)     
nummer = count(8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second recursive call lacks a `return` statement, so that branch will always return `None`. You will need to explicitly return the result of `count` there, i.e.

```py
return count(new)
```

Answer (score 1):

you cannot return the value in other conditions. Try this

```
def count(num):
    if (num > 10):
        return(num)
    if(num<=10):
        new = num + 1
        return count(new)     
nummer = count(8)
```